# Как реализовать элемент списка как на скриншоте Android

Tags: java, android

В общем есть очень красивый список у приложений **Telegram**, **Gmail** .
В нем можно сдвигом влево или вправо выполнять какие-то действия, но то есть стоит слушатель и т.д.

Покопался везде и не смог найти как это называется, очень надеюсь что кто-то знает и это не надо писать самому.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]